# How to get the correct XPath for a column title using C# and selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have the following HTML

```
<label class="ms-Label headerText-269" title="Reference Id">Reference Id</label>
```

which I am trying to locate using XPath. I have written the following which doesn't seem to work.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//title[contains(text(),'Reference Id']"));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Try the below***

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[contains(text(),'Reference Id']"));
```

***OR***

```
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[normalize-space()='Reference Id']"));
```

Comment: Not sure why, but the normalize-space worked when all else failed. Thanks very much!

Comment: Great ! - Please upvote and accept if this solve your issue, you can read about the difference here http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2018/09/30/advanced-xpath-concept-method-normalize-space-its-usage/

Answer (score 1):

In this element the tag name is `label` while `title` is attribute name as well as `class` is attribute name.
XPath expression is normally has the following structure

```xml
//tagname[@attributeName='attributeValue']
```

or

```xml
//tagname[contains(@attributeName,'attributeValue')]
```

etc.
So, you can try the following command:

```cs
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[contains(text(),'Reference Id')]"));
```

Or

```cs
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[contains(.,'Reference Id')]"));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could identify the xpath based attributes.

If you want identify by its `text` then

```
//label[text()='Reference Id']
```

By `title` attribute

```
//label[@title='Reference Id']
```

So your c# code should be like

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[text()='Reference Id']"));
```

Or

```
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[@title='Reference Id']"));
```

You can refer following reference to understand more about `xpath`
[xpath](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/xpath-writing-cheat-sheet-tutorial-examples/)

Answer (score 1):

Here the tagname is `label`, also we can directly use the text() instead of contains() if the text `Reference id` is static. The xpath would be:

`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[text()='Reference Id']"));`